Adding chemical formulae together - only takes inputs individually rather than a range of cells
I have here a UDF in VBA which adds chemical formulae together based on their elements. I'll admit it's not the most efficient, but it kinda works so far. What it basically does is it takes inputs like C6H12O5 and HPO3, then adds them together to spit out C6H13O8P. That part works great!
What doesn't work so great is that each formula has to be put in individually in the Excel worksheet:
ConcatenateMolecules(A1, A2, A3, A4, A5)
And it doesn't like taking cells in a range all together:
ConcatenateMolecules(A1:A5)
Doing this always returns a VALUE error.
I'm very new to coding in general and VBA isn't my main language, so i was hoping to have another set of eyes look over what's been written so far and see where the problem lies.
Here is the function so far!
Option Explicit

Function ConcatenateMolecules(ByVal Molecule As String, ParamArray Molecules()) As String
  Dim i As Integer
  'Create space for the analyser
  Dim Numbers, Elements
  Numbers = Array()
  Elements = Array()
  'Analyse each molecule and combine the elements
  AnalyseMolecule Molecule, Elements, Numbers
  For i = 0 To UBound(Molecules)
    AnalyseMolecule Molecules(i), Elements, Numbers
  Next
  'Create space for the output
  ReDim Result(0 To UBound(Elements))
  For i = 0 To UBound(Elements)
    If Numbers(i) = 1 Then
      Result(i) = Elements(i)
    Else
      Result(i) = Elements(i) & CStr(Numbers(i))
    End If
  Next
  ConcatenateMolecules = Join(Result, "")
End Function

Sub AnalyseMolecule(ByVal S As String, ByRef Elements, ByRef Numbers)
  Dim Digit As String, Element As String, Number As String
  Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
  Dim Last As Boolean
  'Parse the string
  For i = 1 To Len(S)
    Digit = Mid$(S, i, 1)
    'Are we at the start of an element?
    Select Case Digit
      Case "A" To "Z"
        'Do we have a previous Element?
GrabLast:
        If Len(Element) > 0 Then
          For j = LBound(Elements) To UBound(Elements)
            If StrComp(Element, Elements(j), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
              'Found
              Exit For
            End If
          Next
          'Found?
          If j > UBound(Elements) Then
            'No, add a slot
            j = UBound(Elements) + 1
            ReDim Preserve Elements(0 To j)
            ReDim Preserve Numbers(0 To j)
            'Store the element
            Elements(j) = Element
          End If
          'Add the amount of atoms
          If Number = "" Then
            Numbers(j) = Numbers(j) + 1
          Else
            Numbers(j) = Numbers(j) + CInt(Number)
          End If
        End If
        'Done?
        If i > Len(S) Then Exit Sub
        'Prepare for the next round
        Element = Digit
        Number = ""
      Case "a" To "z"
        Element = Element & Digit
      Case "0" To "9"
        Number = Number & Digit
    End Select
  Next
  'Grab the last one
  GoTo GrabLast
End Sub

I've considered other things like defining the input as a range instead, though I'm not really sure how that works myself. I would be grateful for any advice, or if there are any recommendations on how this very non-optimised code could be streamlined. Thanks!

It looks like you are able to go over the problem yourself. Just the hint. Declare Function ConcatenateMolecules(Molecule As Variant, ParamArray Molecules()) As String. Then analyze IsArray(Molecule).

There is no need to process those Molecule and Molecules arguments separately. However, we need to check if Molecules(i) is a single value or an array and if it is an array, then each element should be processed separately.
The beginning of the code can look like this:
Function ConcatenateMolecules(ParamArray Molecules()) As String
  Dim i As Integer
  'Create space for the analyser
  Dim Numbers, Elements
  Numbers = Array()
  Elements = Array()
  'Analyse each molecule and combine the elements
'  AnalyseMolecule Molecule, Elements, Numbers
  Dim m
  For i = 0 To UBound(Molecules)
    If IsArray(Molecules(i)) Then
       For Each m In Molecules(i)
          AnalyseMolecule m, Elements, Numbers
       Next m
    Else
       AnalyseMolecule Molecules(i), Elements, Numbers
    End If
  Next

Regardless, even without changing anything in your code, you can call your function with CONCAT, e.g.
=ConcatenateMolecules(CONCAT(A1:A5))
